# Is it possible to compare against zero value in a generic method extending Number?

Tags: java, generics, comparable

I currently have a method to return the non-zero indices in an iterable. I want this method to be able to handle any class extending `java.lang.Number`. `Number`, of course, does not implement `Comparable`. But I don't want to have separate methods for Long, Integer, etc. As of now, this is what I have:

```
public static <T extends Number & Comparable<? super T>> nonZeroIndices(Iterable<T> iterable) {
    Set<Integer> nonzero_indices = Sets.newTreeSet();
    Iterator<T> iterator = iterable.iterator();
    int i = 0;
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        T t = iterator.next();
        if (t.doubleValue() != 0) // This is what is bothering me
            nonzero_indices.add(i);
        i++;
    }
    return nonzero_indices;
}
```

But I want to avoid `doubleValue()`. I would also like to avoid having a bunch `instanceOf` calls in my method. Can I make this method to work on type `T` where `T extends Number` **and** `T implements Comparable`?

**EDIT**
Using `<T extends Number & Comparable<? super T>>` (as suggested by Sotirios) will still require a bunch of `instanceOf` statements, which I want to avoid. I was hoping that I can safely cast zero to type `T`, but the compiler issues a warning saying "unchecked cast".

To be more specific, I tried

```
if (t.compareTo((T) new Integer(0) == 0)
```

but it issues the warning.

Comment: Made edit to specify how the answers there don't entirely solve my problem. But the answers there DID help to some extent, so thank you :-)

Comment: The Comparable interface is really only useful for comparing the same types. If you want to check that the value is 0, you will necessarily have to use one of the `xValue()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `Integer` is specifically `Comparable<Integer>`, `Double` is specifically `Comparable<Double>`, and so on, so to use their `compareTo`, you have to pass in a reference of the appropriate type, which means that you have to have an object of the appropriate type. Note that the cast in `(Double) new Integer(0)` will never succeed, because you can't have a reference of one type that points to an object of an incompatible type. (And actually it's a compile error, because the compiler can tell in this case that the cast will never succeed.)

I think your `doubleValue` approach is probably the best one.

Comment: I was hoping to find a way around this, especially since algebraically, the integer zero is the additive zero of the `Integer` class is also the additive zero of all the other classes extending `Number`. This, of course, is from the perspective of fields, rings or groups ... not from a programming point of view.

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible with the `Number` hierarchy. You have to use `instanceof`.

In general, your `doubleValue` trick seems to work most of the time. I could construct a false positive with `BigDecimal`:

`new BigDecimal("0.000..<repeats 380 times>..001").doubleValue() == 0`

If that is a problem for you, you might want to add a special case for `BigDecimal`.

Comment: Thanks for this insight. Hadn't thought of BigDecimals at all. For now, I don't need to worry about this, but I will add this case to the code. Otherwise, some dark buggy night in the future, I may die :P